# draw a route in android maps

Tags: android, gps, routes, geopositioning

In the following code:

if(c.moveToFirst())

```
    {


     do{


   longitude=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0));


   latitude=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(1));


    p = new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude);


   geoPointsArray.add(p);


   theRouteDraw();


   }while(c.moveToNext());


     }
```

Where c is cursor obtained form a database where I have stored GPS data (longitude,latitude)

```
          Cursor c=db.getAllData();
```

And:

theRouteDraw();  is a method that draws a line between two GPS points.

In the way I proceeded above in my     geoPointsArray[] I have all this points and then

I pass it to  theRouteDraw(); where the line between this points is drawn instantly!!!!

Now I wanna set a delay in the above code in order to put a point in  geoPointsArray[] and call theRouteDraw().......the line to be drawn step by step

If I don't use a delay my app gets blocked for a while(not FC) until the line is drawn......cause it gets to manyy points which need to be connected on the map!!

Any idea how to do that?????????????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a separate thread to perform the `theRouteDraw()` function: see the `AsyncTask` class and examples (such as http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/) for how to do that.

This will prevent your app from blocking.

Comment: No, the problem is not the blocking part(which appears because it has to many points to draw line between) but how could I introduce a delay or something of this kind in order to for my method theRouteDraw() to receive points step by step....so everything woyld work as a real time app

Comment: Well, the logic is the same: if you have your data coming in bits and pieces you need to have a separate thread updating the route overlay and then re-rendering the overlay on the main UI thread whenever you decide you have received enough points.

Comment: Can I use a separate thread even if I'm reading the data from a database?